# AngularJS ng-show when some value is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display one symbol () when one or more of the values in a scope ($filter.producers) is set to true, and another one (X) when all the values are false. I am trying to do show with ng-show, but I cannot find the way to make it work.

My html goes like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 {{ctrlTest}}
    <span ng-show="filter.producers == false">X</span>
    <span ng-show="filter.producers != false"></span>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="elements in filter">
        <div>
            <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filter.producers" ng-show="value">{{key}}
            <a ng-click="filter.producers[key]=false"> X</a>
            </li>
        </div>
        {{filter.producers}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.ctrlTest = "Filters";
$scope.filter = {
  "producers": {
    "Ford": true,
    "Honda": true,
    "Ferrari": true
  }   
}
});
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/ba77zwqs/3/)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is not clear. Please provide a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: you forgot to ask the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of filter.producers in your case, is this object:　{"Ford": true, ..}. It certainly will not equals to true or false! If I get you question correctly, what you should do is plucking all it's value and check if any of these value is true or false, something like this:

```
//In your controller
 $scope.anyProducerTrue = function() {
    var anyTrue = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.filter.producers, function(value, key) {
      if (true == value) anyTrue = true;
    });
    return anyTrue;
  }

//In your view
<span ng-show="!anyProducerTrue()">X</span>
<span ng-show="anyProducerTrue()"></span>
```

Comment: Works perfect, and it is the cleaner solution. I will mark it as valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need another function to check all properties are `true` or `false` initially and when click `(X)` link to set `false` for a specific property and do not need two `ng-repeat` in your DOM. you can try my solution.

like:

your controller:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlTest = "Filters";
    $scope.filter = {
      "producers": {
        "Ford": true,
        "Honda": true,
        "Ferrari": true
      }
    };
    $scope.hideMe = function(key) {
        $scope.filter.producers[key]=false;
        $scope.checkAllproperty(); // call again to check all property
    };

    $scope.checkAllproperty = function() {
     var allTrue = false;
        for(var key in $scope.filter.producers) {
          if($scope.filter.producers[key] === true){
            allTrue = true;
          }
        }
      $scope.allTrue = allTrue;
    };

    $scope.checkAllproperty(); // initial call when loaded
  });
```

in html: call a `hideMe` function to set false

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{ctrlTest}}
  <span ng-show="!allTrue">X</span>
  <span ng-show="allTrue"></span>
  <p>
  {{filter.brewers}}
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <div>
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filter.producers" ng-show="value">{{key}}
        <a ng-click="hideMe(key)"> X</a> // call to set this key false
      </li>
    </div>
    {{filter.producers}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**use**

```
Object.keys(filter.producers).length;

<span ng-show="Object.keys(filter.producers).length != 0"></span>
```

[JSBIN](https://output.jsbin.com/gekotozuvu)

Comment: Tried the solution in your JSBin, but it doesn't change the symbol when all values set to false

Comment: What is the mean of this line of your question body ? `when one or more of the values in a scope ($filter.producers)` . Now you are saying another scenario

Comment: if fx $scope.filter = {
  "producers": {
    "Ford": false,
    "Honda": false,
    "Ferrari": true
  }   
} I want the  to appear

Comment: but if  $scope.filter = { "producers": { "Ford": false, "Honda": false, "Ferrari": false } } I want the X to appear

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JS `Array.prototype.some` function in your controller as follows:

```
$scope.flag = Object.keys($scope.filter.producers).some(
  function(el) {
    return $scope.filter.producers[el];
  });
```

and in your HTML use the flag as follows:

```
<span ng-show="!flag">X</span>
<span ng-show="flag"></span>
```

Comment: I tried you solution but it doesn't seem to change the icon when all the values are false, check this updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ba77zwqs/5/

Comment: you need to click on the 'run' button after changing all to false

Comment: here's the same code with all of them set to false: http://jsfiddle.net/asafusan/fm5kers7/2/

Comment: I just can make it work when setting manually all the values of the scope to false, so that is slightly different to my question, but thanks for the approach anyway.